# SQL Server: Get current user without domain

Tags: sql-server

I know I can use `SELECT SUSER_SNAME()` to get the current user name. But in an AD environment I would get the user including domain (e.g. "MyDomain\User").

Is there any function to just receive the username excluding domain?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SELECT nt_username FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

or

```
SELECT nt_user_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 has `nt_user_name` as the column name for `sys.dm_exec_sessions`.

Comment: This requires additional privileges that the user might not have access to

Answer (score 31):

```
select stuff(suser_sname(), 1, charindex('\', suser_sname()), '')
```

Comment: of course I could parse the returned string, but I like using built in stuff instead of string parsing ;-)

Comment: I prefer this method because it doesn't depend on the login having a session. It works for any name you can spell.

Comment: @IainElder in what situations would you not have a session?

Comment: This answer also works for local accounts (if there is no slash).